# MySQL IF() Sub Select

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having trouble with doing a SUB SELECT in an IF() condition.

I'm trying to get it to select select the MIN saved time if the type does not equal a certain value, excluding that value from the calculation.

Here is my current SQL query that works except for the IF():

```
SELECT
t.episode,
t.anime_id,
MAX(t.type) as type,
MIN(t.HD) as HD,
MAX(t.thumbnail) as thumbnail,
IF((MAX(t.type)!="raw"),(SELECT MIN(e.saved) FROM anime_episodes e WHERE e.type=MAX(t.type) AND t.episode=e.episode AND t.anime_id=e.anime_id GROUP BY e.anime_id, e.episode), (MIN(t.saved))) as time,
// UP HERE ^
MAX(t.filler) as filler,
m.anime_name,
m.furl,
m.video_thumb
FROM anime_episodes t
LEFT JOIN anime_list m ON
( t.anime_id=m.anime_id )
WHERE t.approved=1 AND t.locked=0 AND m.status=0 AND t.episode>=m.latest_ep
GROUP BY t.anime_id, t.episode
ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 0,24
```

Is there something going on with my syntax? It looks fine to me but the error is:

```
SQL error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE type!="raw")) as time, MAX(t.filler) as filler,m.anime_name, m.furl, m.vid' at line 1
```

EDIT: Correct answer, but I had to add some grouping as it was returning more than one result. Thank you!

Comment: Unrelated to your error, but your WHERE clause is checking the value of m.status to be 0. As this can only be true if there is a row found on anime_list the LEFT OUTER JOIN is not useful. An INNER JOIN will give you exactly the same result, but if you only want to match against status 0 records then keep using the LEFT OUTER JOIN but more the check for m.status into the ON clause of the JOIN (same for the AND t.episode>=m.latest_ep)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgot to add the `from table` statement

Try this::

```
SELECT
t.episode,
t.anime_id,
MAX(t.type) as type,
MIN(t.HD) as HD,
MAX(t.thumbnail) as thumbnail,
IF((type="raw"),(MIN(t.saved)), (SELECT MIN(saved) from  anime_episodes WHERE type!="raw")) as time,
// UP HERE ^
MAX(t.filler) as filler,
m.anime_name,
m.furl,
m.video_thumb
FROM anime_episodes t
LEFT JOIN anime_list m ON
( t.anime_id=m.anime_id )
WHERE t.approved=1 AND t.locked=0 AND m.status=0 AND t.episode>=m.latest_ep
GROUP BY t.anime_id, t.episode
ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 0,24
```

Comment: I believe the table is anime_episodes, considering the beginning of the IF statement he selects type = raw there as well. even though he's not aliasing t.type...

Comment: Thank you! However it turns out I had to do some additions for other reasons.